# How to share files from Win7 to remote Lubunto desktop server

Tags: networking, server, remote, sharing

Could you kindly recommend a tutorial or the right software for sharing files between a computer Win 7 OS and a Lubuntu Desktop OS server? they are not on the same network.

Thanks

B

Comment: nevermind, i used WinSCP